# what is the win explorer location of chrome's "settings" data?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, vbscript, explorer, wsh

I have the following script to dump google's junk out of windows when using chrome (this is just partial script):

```
For Each f In FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default").Files
   If FSO.FileExists(f) Then
      if f.name<>"Bookmarks" and f.name<>"Preferences" and f.name<>"Login Data" then
         FSO.DeleteFile f
      end if
   end if
next

msgbox "All tracking data in chrome has been deleted!"
```

there is more to this script too, and above that code is more that deletes specific dirs in the "default" profile folder.  but does anyone know where google's profile settings are located?  there are no files or dirs that indicate the obvious like bookmarks and and autofill data.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> does anyone know where google's profile settings are located?

AFAIK, it's not a '*setting*' per se, but rather, a computed value from the internal `GetDefaultUserDataDirectory()` [function](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_paths_internal.h?q=GetDefaultUserDataDirectory&l=28)

On Windows, this defaults to: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data` [directory location](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#windows)

However, it can be overridden using the `chrome.exe --user-data-dir=c:\foo` [command-line startup flag](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#command-line)

Within Google Chrome, you can check and confirm the location by visiting `chrome://version` [URL](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#current-location)

Hope this info helps.

Comment: hey thank you so much!  I will look at it.  I'm sorry for the private comment.  I have no ability here to post publicly for some strange reason.